# Whats wrong with my If-Else conditional code that receives user input and categorizes the data by "hot" or "cold"

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

```
HighTemp1= input()
print(‘Temperature 1:’ +  HighTemp1)
LowTemp2= input()
print(‘Temperature 2:’ + LowTemp2)
if (HighTemp1>80):
   print( ‘The high temperature was Hot’)
elif(HighTemp1> 40 and <80):
   print(‘The high temperature was Average’)
else:
   print(‘The high temperature was Cold’)

if (LowTemp2>80):
   print( ‘The low temperature was Hot’)
elif(LowTemp2> 40 and <80):
   print(‘The low temperature was Average’)
else:
   print(‘The low temperature was Cold’)
```

So, i'm suppose to Determine the category of two user-input temperatures for a day and output it in the following way:

```
Temp        Category
>80         Hot
40 to 80    Average
<40         Cold
```

Example#1:
Temperature 1: 81 
Temperature 2: 37
The high temperature was Hot
The low temperature was Cold

I've gotten so many errors on this code and I'm not sure what's wrong. The code won't run in IDLE because as I run it line by line(since I get a multiple statement error), there's either a type error "cannot use > operator with both int and string" or a syntax error. What am I not understanding that's preventing my code from running?

Comment: try this : HighTemp1=int( input());

LowTemp2= int(input());

Comment: input() reads input as a string and you can't run compare string with int

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#44>", line 1, in <module>
    HighTemp1=int( input());
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Another testcase for you; `80` for either high or low.

Comment: Are you saying remove the inequality and put 80= for either high or low?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using **Python3**. You're having a number of errors in your code

```
HighTemp1= int(input())  #to take int input, you need to parse it to int. as input() directly reads a string
print("Temperature 1:" +  str(HighTemp1)) #print in python3 assumes string in "" 
LowTemp2= int(input())
print("Temperature 2:" + str(LowTemp2)) #int can't be directly concatenated to string. You need to parse it to string using str() to concat it with string
if (HighTemp1>80):
    print( "The high temperature was Hot")
elif(HighTemp1> 40 and  <80):
    print("The high temperature was Average")
else:
    print("The high temperature was Cold")

if (LowTemp2>80):
    print( "The low temperature was Hot")
elif(LowTemp2> 40 and <80):
    print("The low temperature was Average")
else:
    print("The low temperature was Cold")
```

Comment: It's great to post an answer, but you should really make sure it runs before you do. The above **elif**s must fail.

Comment: you didn't mention for that elif to fail. That's a logical error. You should look out for it. I removed your error

Answer (score 0):

First, `input()` returns a *string*. You need to cast it into an *int* for your comparisons.
Second, watch your "quotes". The characters you use in your strings as quotes are not simple ASCII. I replaced them all.
Third, your comparisons were flawed. I redid the "high" ones and merely fixed the "low" ones. You can see the difference.
Also, the `input()` method takes a string as an input arg to output to the user, so s/he knows to input something. Probably a good thing to do.

```
HighTemp1 = int(input('High: ').strip())
print('Temperature 1: %d' %  HighTemp1)
LowTemp2= int(input('Low: ').strip())
print('Temperature 2: %d' % LowTemp2)
if HighTemp1 > 80:
   print('The high temperature was Hot')
# elif 40 < HighTemp1 <= 80: # simplifies to next line
elif HighTemp1 > 40:
   print('The high temperature was Average')
else:
   print('The high temperature was Cold')

if (LowTemp2 > 80):  # parens not required here
   print('The low temperature was Hot')
elif(LowTemp2 > 40):  # and LowTemp2<=80):
#                     # the above is redundant
# note that your original "and LowTemp2<80" introduced a bug for value 80
   print('The low temperature was Average')
else:
   print('The low temperature was Cold')
```